# change url without making page postback -- mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there is a way to chage the url without making page postback using MVC.My requirement is , i am having a page,on a button click only small portion of page get updated.I also want to change the url on that updation. I dont have much idea about "MVC".So please let me know if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **HTML5-able** browser and some JavaScript. [Here](http://html5demos.com/history/) is the demo of HTML5 history feature.

[GitHub](https://github.com/) implemented that feature for [tree browsing](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider). And there is [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) in [railscast.com](http://railscasts.com).

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid not. To display a different you URL you would have to browse to that URL which would involve another request.

You could update part of your page using an AJAX call that fires on your button click.