# Change the URL in partial post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am developing a shopping site where user can search products using different criteria.

On checked_changed event of check box i want to change URL, but condition is that my page does not make full post back..

Comment: So you'd like to do a full postback? If so, you could call __doPostBack from JS http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/11/04/59081.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you......

You need **HTML5-able** browser and some JavaScript. [Here](http://html5demos.com/history/) is the demo of HTML5 history feature.

[GitHub](https://github.com/) implemented that feature for [tree browsing](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider). And there is [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) in [railscast.com](http://railscasts.com).

Original answer is :
[change url without making page postback -- mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026403/change-url-without-making-page-postback-mvc)

Comment: i don't want to use HTML5 and i am not using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the solution http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ - asual provides the functionality for easily changing addresses on the fly

Answer (score 0):

What I can see there is the same functionality where we link an anchor tag to a div in the same page by appending #. You can see the the URL is changing by just appending the **#!gender=men/page=1** to the end.

Also there is no checkbox. I saw that portion in firebug. Its just an image. But we can achieve it through checkbox as well on the onclick event but just appending the **#[your params]** to the URL.

Thanks,

Sayed.

Comment: @Sayed.u r right,but i want to change URL from "www.test.com/showAllResult.aspx?StudentId=845212563" to "www.test.com/DetailResult.aspx". is it possible using partial postback and javascript??